# Remove nodes from a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, dom, nodes

I am trying to remove (almost) all nodes from a form. I managed to remove all nodes from the form using the following code:

```
var form;
form = document.getElementById(id);
while (form.hasChildNodes())
    form.removeChild(form.lastChild);
```

However, that will not suffice because I will be adding some logic to keep certain nodes. Therefore, I need to remove the nodes using a `for loop`. I tried with the following code:

```
var form, formNodes, totalNodes, i;
form = document.getElementById(id);
formNodes = form.childNodes;
totalNodes = formNodes.length;
for (i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++)
    form.removeChild(formNodes[i]);
```

Some nodes are removed, but I received this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Considering `formNodes` only contains nodes, what could be causing the error?

### Edit

I tried looping backwards using the following code:

```
var form, formNodes, totalNodes, i;
form = document.getElementById(id);
formNodes = form.childNodes;
totalNodes = formNodes.length;
for (i = totalNodes - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    form.removeChild(formNodes[i]);
```

And it removes all nodes. I'll subtract an offset variable from `i` so that I am able to keep certain nodes.

### Edit

My question is different because I am trying to remove nodes from a form, not using `getElementsByTagName` to get paragraph elements. A `node` is not the same as an `element`. The solution to my question may be similar but the question is not the same.

Comment: Do you still have a question left over after your edits?

Comment: I know, I just spotted the error and edited my question.

Comment: @trincot sort of. I am still deciding on the best solution. I could use `Array.prototype.slice`. It would be simpler but it would be more efficient to run the for loop backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `childNodes` property updates as you remove children.

Therefore, once you remove half of the children, your index will be past the end of the updated NodeList.

You should either loop backwards (so that the indices never adjust) or copy to an array in advance.  Or just keep deleting the first child until the NodeList is empty.

Comment: I can't keep deleting the first child until the NodeList is empty because I will be adding logic to keep certain nodes. I tried running the loop backwards and that did not work. I've shown that in my edit.

Comment: Running that backwards should work.  Use the debugger to see what it's doing.

Comment: I forgot to change the `++` to `--` so of course it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `form.childNodes` returns a `live collection`, you can use `querySelectorAll()` instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var formNodes = form.querySelectorAll('*');
var totalNodes = formNodes.length;
for (i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {
    formNodes[i].remove();
}
```

**Custom logic**

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var formNodes = form.childNodes; // live
var totalNodes = formNodes.length;
var removed = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {
    if (odds(i)) {
        form.removeChild(formNodes[i - removed]);
        removed++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code removes almost all nodes but it leaves some text.